# How to access 'otherwise' property of $urlRouterProvider in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Under certain circumstances I would like to navigate to the default or 'otherwise' state. So I need to obtain from a controller what is the otherwise state as configured in the routing object.

When I try to inject `$urlRouterProvider` in the controller of my directive, I get an error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider <-
>   $stateProvider <- bbvNavDirective

What am I doing wrong?

Example code:

```
.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) => {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/bbv/voorstellen/open');

    (...routing code)

}])
```

Directive:

```
    .directive('bbvNav', [ '$state', ( $state ) => {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template,
            scope: {
                titleBind: '&',
                onButtonClick: '&'
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controller: [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
                $state.go( <NAVIGATE TO URLROUTERPOVIDER.OTHERWISE> );
                console.log('Accessing $urlRouterProvider.otherwise state:'); // How do I get the value of $urlRouterProvider.otherwise here?
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you give us code sample ? It's far more difficult to guess what's going on without your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using such an approach for this situation.
First I always **put my default state in a constant** so whenever I need it I just inject constant to controller or service to use it...

**CONSTANT**

```
app.module('example').constant('defaultState','app.defaultState')
```

then first inject it in your config file and use with `$urlprovider`

**CONFIG**

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, defaultState) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $state.go(defaultState);
});
```

so with constant always there just inject it any component you want and use it...

**CONTROLLER EXAMPLE**

```
.controller(defaultState){
   ... TODO ...
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting strategy. Will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the naming used in your directive. You should change injection name like that :

```
.directive('bbvNav', [ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ( $state, $urlRouter ) => {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template,
            scope: {
                titleBind: '&',
                onButtonClick: '&'
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controller: [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
                console.log('Accessing otherwise state:'); // How do I get the value of $urlRouterProvider.otherwise here?
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, that doesn't seem to work: same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading directive module as dependencies of your main app module. for example use:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directive']);
```

**Note** that:

```
angular.module('ModuleName', [])   // creates a module.
angular.module('ModuleName')       // gets you a pre-existing module.
```

Comment: My directive is already loaded by the app, that is not the problem. I am trying to access the value that I have set in the routing otherwise parameter. How do I get that value?

Comment: @Squrler Your error *Unknown provider* comes from the reality that I said. I don't know more my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you cannot inject provider in directives, just in config...
But if you want to access the current route in controller/service/directive/..., you can inject `$route` and use it as follows:

```
$route.current : {scope, params, templateUrl}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

also in event `$routeChangeSuccess / $routeChangeStart` you can access next route through second argument

for more support please tell me, which information you need from "otherwise" state, that we can find a solution together :)

## Update

Sorry, i skipped, that you are using the ui-router, my answer was made for "ngRoute", but i think it is quite similar. You should get access to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` through `$state`

### update:

```
(function(){
    // wrap to prevent user to interact with
    var urlProvider;
    app.config(["$urlProvider", function(provider){
        urlProvider = provider;
    }]);
    app.directive([...]{
        console.log(urlProvider); // log provider to see if you can access otherwise ( like $$otherwise ), due to otherwise is a function
    })
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The otherwise parameter isn't a part of $state at all. Which is what leads me to think I should get it from $urlRouterProvider somehow.

Comment: which information do you expect to get from `otherwise`? maybe i know where else you can acces this information. but you can not access the provider unless you save it into a variable and use that in your directive, i will mke a update with a short snippet

Comment: With '.otherwise', as far as I understand it, I set a default view, the view that is loaded when no URL is matched specifically. I want to access the name of that state, so I can navigate to it. In my directive want to do something like: ```$state.go(defaultState);```

Comment: how about saving defaultState into variable or constant and refer to that in your directive?

Answer (score 0):

Store state and stateParams at rootScope

```
 .run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        })
```

Use $state.go("state-name") to desired state

```
$rootScope.$state.go("state-name");
```

I tried to demonstrate with following plunker

Description: Click on State2 or State 3 and then Click Home button,one will be redirected to home page.

[demo to route to desired state](http://plnkr.co/edit/k6MYaO?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the question correctly. Take this scenario: User enters a detail view, and wants to navigate back to the home view. I'll won't have set the home state to the rootScope as you suggest. I know how to transition from one state to another with $state.go, but now I need to know what the name of the default state is before I can navigate to it. I want to obtain what the default view is from my UI Router configuration so I can navigate to it, instead of hard coding it.